# Is it possible to import my photos to react native app and share them to instagram

Tags: react-native, instagram, share, gallery

I'm trying to build a react native app that imports my photos from my gallery (plus if I can sort them by favorites or not) and then share them to instagram. I'm trying to look if that's even possible but I can't find anything conclusive about it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Expo image picker.
First, you have to grant permission in order to access the storage device then you use the image picker.

```
npm i expo-permissions 

npm install expo-image-picker
```